# Batch Script, Find String in text file and seperate into multiple output files

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file we will call info.txt, this text file contains a number of long lines that each have a number of tags within the line like this:

```
A bunch of usless info {tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data {Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}
```

So in this document I need to locate {Tag15} and pull everything between {Tag15} and {Tag11} or it could be another {Tag15} and drop that segment of data into a new text file. So that I have one 15.txt and one 11.txt that contain the right segments of data including all of the tags between it and the next Tag string. So in this example 15.txt would contain:

```
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data data {Tag3}data 
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data
```

And 11.txt would contain:

```
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data {Tag3}data
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data
```

That being said the most logical way I can see of doing this would be to find all Tag15's and Tag11's and move them to a new line so we don't have to determine how long the data set is since it can very for each tag set. Than process the file through another findstr and pull each matching line out to the appropriate file. What I don't know how to do is insert a new line at the exact point in the line that {tag15} or {tag11} was found. Any thoughts?

In total the text file will contain about 200-300 of these tag sets that need to be parsed and sorted to the appropriate txt files. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

I am open to other solutions than just batch, it just happens to be what I am most comfortable with.

edit:

I can understand why more information is needed here and apologize for not providing it to begin with. So the tag segments in the each line of the source file will always start with {tag15} or {tag11}, but the tags that follow within that segment can vary depending on the data being pushed through for example if Tag2 is populated with Y than Tag3 is required but if Tag2 is N than Tag3 won't exist in the segment, but tag5,6, or 200 might. This is why I felt it best to locate Tag15 or 11 and move it to its own line so you wouldn't have to depend upon trying to determine the length of the string you want to move. The example 15.txt and 11.txt were meant to illustrate what it may look like due to different data per segment, but here is what the source file MAY look like that produced those:

```
Line1: FirstLast 55555555 10092013 0000000 {tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data {tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data data {Tag3}data {Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data {Tag3}data
Line2: FirstLast 444444444 10092013 000000005 {Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data {tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data {Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data
```

My thoughts are you take this file that has all of the data in it and find the Tag15 and Tag11 and move them to their own line so the file would look something like this:

```
FirstLast 55555555 10092013 0000000 
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data 
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data data {Tag3}data 
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data data {Tag3}data
FirstLast 444444444 10092013 000000005 
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data 
{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data 
{Tag11}data {Tag1}data {Tag2}data data
```

Now that each line is its own segment we would simply run a For loop with Findstr and echo the lines to the correct txt file or did I miss something? My biggest issue as previously mentioned is I'm unsure of how to get the file from its original state to the above example so that it can be sorted without needing to know the exact length of the string we are trying to extract. I hope this helps

Comment: Please give a better descrption of what you are extracting and what you want in the target file.  You have shown one line in your source file and have three lines in your target file.  Please show input and output clearly.

Comment: I agree with foxidrive.  I can't fathom how you can logically expect to get your 15.txt and 11.txt output from the one line of input that you posted.

Comment: There is no pattern. Example: what about `{Tag3}`? Or where comes the last `data` in `{tag15}data data{Tag1}data {Tag2}data data` ? Mor explanation needed.

Comment: This sounds like a task for `awk`

Comment: I hope the detail I added helps. Please let me knkow if you need further explanation. I think because I had to change tag names and can't provide exact data examples due to the sensative nature of the data I may have over simplified my examples to begin with. Each Tag segment can contain thousands of characters and up to 40 different tags between each tag15 and tag11.

Comment: @Floris - I was looking at AWK and see that it is specifically for text editing/filtering, but I'm afraid I don't know it. Can you give an example of how I can accomplish this with AWK?

Comment: How long is a line of text?  Batch files have issues with extremely long lines.

Comment: One of the lines is over 4million characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a tool I was a bit more comfortable with and installed Sed for windows. I got this idea from the suggestion of using AWK. Since this script will only run in one place I decided the installation of a non native tool wasn't an issue. Here is what I came up with to solve this problem:

```
Set sed=(the path to sed.exe for windows)
set filedir=Dir the source file is in
set file=name of source file
set wout=tag15.txt 
set win=tag11.txt

:: Locate "FTI0811 " which occurs prior to every {Tag15} tag and call a new line
%sed% -i -c --expression="s/FTI0811 /&\n/g" %filedir%%file%
:: Locate XFT811  which occurs prior to every {Tag11} tag and call a new line
%sed% -i -c --expression="s/XFT811 /&\n/g" %filedir%%file%
:: Find all strings that start with {Tag15} and echo them out to the Wires Out file variable
findstr "{tag15}" %filedir%%file% >> %wout%
:: Find all strings that start with {tag11} and echo them out to the Wires In file variable
findstr "{tag11}" %filedir%%file% >> %win%
```

Thank you everyone for your help and ideas. Please feel free to edit/comment on my method for doing this I'm always more than happy to get feed back. Sorry that the question was a bit murky for some, Due to my job I couldn't post the entirety of the source file and what it contains. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Put `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file and text file.

Try this command on a sample of your file - the `i` in `ix` is to make it case insensitive as your tags are in different case.

```
type file.txt |repl "{tag15}" "\r\n{tag15}" ix |repl "{tag11}" "\r\n{tag11}" ix >newfile.txt
```

The task is still very muddy/unclear.